# In this design should title precede image or vice versa?

Tags: design, text, image, title, order

I created two designs in Balsamiq, in the first one the titles "International Flights/Domestic Flights" come on top of their corresponding images and in the other one it is the other way around. Both, have a "Learn More" link.

Which of these two designs is preferred and why?

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlSwM.jpg />

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make the following adjustments:

- Make the title itself the link, instead of using the text "learn more". Thus, the original question becomes irrelevant. This will also be better for SEO, because your links don't have a generic text like "click here" or "learn more".
- The images are not informative - use a picture that meaningfully differentiates "domestic" and "international". To check if you've done a good job: hide the text and swap the images - will the users be able to figure out which is which?

To address your specific question - assuming you decide to keep the "learn more" URL, I see no difference between having it above or below the image, as long as you respect the Gestalt law of proximity, and keep the link close to the image - so it is clear that they are associated.

[image]